# Is it possible to view WebP images in nautilus / photo program?

Tags: nautilus, google, codecs, file-format, webp

I've converted some images from jpeg to google's WebP image format, which reduces my images' size by about 90%!

The big problem is that WebP images can only be viewed with a web browser, not with nautilus (the thumbnails) and/or any photo program at all. It seems that at this moment there is only [a codec for Windows](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/speed/webp/download.html).

Does anyone know if this is also possible in Ubuntu?

Comment: Update: I've posted a bug report here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=659291

Comment: Is this old ?
Actually the last version is 0.2 for cwebp in WebP Project.

Comment: for nautilus, check [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/617068/46437), there is also [this script](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secWebpPreview.sh)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Up to 14.04

There is a [plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/25874) for the GIMP, written by [Nathan Osman](https://askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman).

You can add this plugin from his webptools PPA:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/webp
```

Then install the required package: [gimp-webp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gimp-webp) [image: Install gimp-webp]

```
sudo apt-get install gimp-webp
```

As for thumbnails in nautilus, this seems to be a bug with MIME, as apparently (so I was told) Nautilus already "supports" the webp format, but the thumbnails do not show up as they should.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did not know that there was a ppa for that. I installed it and there are indeed no thumbnails in Nautilus.

As for the thumbnails: that's the most annoying part. I hope this will be solved soon so I can use WebP properly. Now it's still hard to use if you have to open image by image in the web browser...

Comment: there seems to have no package for 14.04? any idea if an older may work?

Comment: I tried [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14112645/1422630) to try to create the thumbnail manually but nautilus ignored the the thumbnail I created for the '.webp', could you give it a try? a bit help on it: `dwebp filename.webp -o "$HOME/.cache/thumbnails/normal/md5summedResult.png" -scale 100 100`

Comment: @AquariusPower packages have now been updated for 14.04.

Answer (score 9):

### Since 16.04

```
display image.webp
```

or for thumbnails

```
display 'vid:*.webp'
```

Imagemagick does support `webp` now, although it uses webp, so you need to install `webp`

```
sudo apt-get install webp
```

Answer (score 6):

Since 14.04 [universe] there is the `vwebp` command in the `webp` package:

```
sudo apt install webp
```

Then:

```
vwebp imagefile.webp
```

To get thumbnails in Nautilus see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/617068/146271) (like *Aquarius Power* said above).