# Which image-viewers in Linux support the `webp` image format?

Tags: xfce, thunar, image-viewers, webp

Is there any way to see WebP photo from Thunar with Xfce DE? There was a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61443/is-it-possible-to-view-webp-images-in-nautilus-photo-program), but it was about nautilus.

Then to get WebP thumbnails [tumbler (the Xfce thumbnailing service) must support](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8951), and there are nothing.

Then to open pictures, the viewer must know WebP.

I tried ristretto, gpicview, viewnior and they all say something like:

> error of interpretation of the image file format jpeg

Comment: I still convert them into some more common format with a bash script: https://askubuntu.com/a/1306737/1157519

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here are the Linux image-viewers, that display webp images:

- [All major browsers](https://caniuse.com/webp), like Chromium based browsers (Chrome/[Brave](https://brave.com/)) or Firefox*
- eog (Eye of GNOME), with [webp-pixbuf-loader](https://github.com/aruiz/webp-pixbuf-loader)
- [Loupe/Image Viewer](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/loupe) (from GNOME)
- feh, with [imlib2-webp](https://github.com/gawen947/imlib2-webp)
- GIMP  `ver 2.10`
- GraphicsMagick
- gThumb  `from trusty-release or above ~3.4.3`
- Gwenview, from KDE
- ImageMagick
- nomacs
- PhotoQt
- [qview](https://github.com/jurplel/qView)
- Thunar // in old system, update [mime-info](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=52057#p52057)
- vwebp (part of libwebp)
- XnViewMP

And others, [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP#Support).

Comment: any of these are as lightweight and user friendly as `eog` ? imagemagick's one (`display`) is not as user friendly as `eog`, `vwebp` is not user friendly at all :>

Comment: gThumb is more user-friendly than `display` and `vwebp`, but is probably "heavier" than eog, because it does have a few more features than eog.

Comment: in no way it is heavier to me at least xD, gThumb's up (pun intened) is excellent!!! thx vm!!! xD, it should be default than eog for sure :)

Comment: I wrote [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1346951/349837) about how to add webp support (webp-pixbuf-loader) to Eye of GNOME (eog)

Comment: gThumb does not seem to support animated WebP images.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for GUI applications, consider GIMP or ImageMagick.

If you have installed the `webp` package, you could use `vwebp file.webp` to view the image, and `dwebp file.webp -o file.png` to convert it to a png file.

See https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/using for details.

Comment: Also, to convert multiple webp files to png, use this: `alias convertwebp="find ./ -name "*.webp" -exec dwebp {} -o {}.png \;; find . -type f -name '*.webp' -delete"`

Answer (score 7):

### [qView](https://github.com/jurplel/qView)

[image: qview]

Since **2018**, there is a really lightweight and user-friendly image viewer called [qView](https://github.com/jurplel/qView) that can view WebP images. It also has a nice feature to resize the window frame to fit the image. It is also free and open source.

You can download the latest version (3.0 at the time of writing, and it's still being actively developed) as a .deb file from the official [website](https://interversehq.com/qview/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/jurplel/qView/releases) and install it with `gdebi` or your software center.

To install from terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jurplel/qview
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get --install-suggests install qview
```

After you install the .deb file, you also need to install this package: **Qt 5 Image Formats add-on**

```
sudo apt install qt5-image-formats-plugins
```

This is because qView is based on Qt5 and even though it supports many common formats by default, it does need this one package to actually view WebP images.

**Note**: this add-on is pre-installed on Lubuntu and Kubuntu (Qt-based DEs, as expected).

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04; Lubuntu 19.10, 20.04.

Answer (score 5):

### In 16.04

```
display 'vid:*.webp'
```

Since 16.04 [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/display.php) does support `webp`, although it apparently delegates decoding to `webp`, so `webp` is needed:

```
sudo apt-get install webp
```

Answer (score 4):

[XNViewMP](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) can view WebP files. Though Tumbler has yet to implement WebP, so the files won't be able to be viewed as thumbnails within Thunar.

Note that it is a [non-free](https://www.gnu.org/proprietary/proprietary.html) software, although freeware.

Comment: It’s need to be mentioned that XNViewMP is non-free.

Answer (score 2):

gThumb also opens/edits webp files.  It has some nice must have quick editing tools.

```
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```

Version 3.4.3 I know supports webp, but does not support animated webp images.

Comment: Sorry Jeff, but this is a repeat of the answer above; unless you add - starting with which version gThumb supports webp ?

Comment: Your right it is, but I wanted to tell people because gthumb is awesome.  I added the version you requested.  Thanks for commenting.

Comment: `gthumb` not support animated webp images, but `qview` can.

Comment: @林果皞, I've verified what your saying about `gthumb` and have updated my answer, thank you for commenting.  Your also right, `qview` does support animated webp images.

Answer (score 1):

Developed by Google, WebP is a new image format that provides lossless and lossy compression for images on the web.

You can download a WebP viewer, and other utilities from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download)

Comment: `Precompiled WebP utilities and library for **Linux**, Windows and Mac OS X.` from the same site.  So its downloadable for [Linux](http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-0.4.2-linux-x86-32.tar.gz).

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, and even set the system libwebp, but the problem is how to do to make things work together lib->thumb->viewer I can not understand. /if possible, then sign for gyide

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stylish looking [deepin-image-viewer](https://www.deepin.org/en/original/deepin-image-viewer/) (from [Deepin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepin) project, a Linux distro based on China) for WebP.

Answer (score 0):

GIMP works well. "Save image as" from the website, navigate to where you saved it, right click "open with", select GIMP and you can then use "File - export as" to export the image from GIMP to your desired destination , remembering to change ".webp" to ".jpg" so that any of your normal programmes will open it.