# How to view `webp` files without using browser?

Tags: webp

Does anyone know if there's a codec or app to let me view `.webp` files without using a browser?

Comment: What do you mean? When I double click on a webp file, it doesn't open in my browser but rather opens up in GIMP, where it loads fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot open 90% of recently saved images (webp format)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232571/cannot-open-90-of-recently-saved-images-webp-format)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [thread](https://www.makeuseof.com/view-webp-images-on-ubuntu-linux-mint/), you can add native support to the default Ubuntu image viewer via the WebP GDK Pixbuf Loader library:

```shell
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:krifa75/eog-ordissimo
sudo apt update
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

An alternative suggestion is [gThumb](https://github.com/GNOME/gthumb):

```shell
sudo apt install gthumb
```