# How to preview DDS and WEBP images on nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, files, previews, webp

I have too many images to search visually, so I cannot open each one of them individually.

What do I have to do or install to show DDS image previews on nautilus?

I would like to preview webp too if possible.

Answer (score 46):

Create files at `/usr/share/thumbnailers` with these names and content:

#### DDS

From [here](http://nowcodingtime.blogspot.com.br/2013/09/thumbnail-dds-texture-files-in-ubuntu.html): Write to `dds.thumbnailer`:

```conf
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/convert -thumbnail x%s %i png:%o
MimeType=image/x-dds;
```

#### WEBP

First install webp: `sudo apt-get install webp`.
Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70673/30352). Write to  `webp.thumbnailer`:
`sudo gedit /usr/share/thumbnailers/webp.thumbnailer`.

```conf
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/dwebp %i -scale 100 100 -o %o
MimeType=image/x-webp;image/webp;
```

and restart nautilus after fully quitting it with `nautilus -q`.

As [pointed by @PereJoanMartorell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617047/how-to-preview-dds-and-webp-images-on-nautilus#comment1807419_617068) I had to remove the files inside `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail` at least.

#### Note

The problem with this webp approach is that all thumbnails will be 100x100 px.
But [this script](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secWebpPreview.sh) makes it work properly (and it can be highly simplified, see the answer below [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223606/46437) , to not depend on ScriptEchoColor libs). Also the improved one based on it, [for animated webp](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322204/46437) (looks interesting, haven't tried it yet tho, just learned webp could be animated!).
**Obs.**: on 18.04 and 20.04 it only works on `nemo`, on nautilus it is failing to generate the thumbnails but works to visualize'm.

Comment: If you replace the 100 with %s you'll get the appropriate size. Like this: Exec=/usr/bin/dwebp %i -scale %s %s -o %o

Comment: @Liminal  I had to update it to mime `image/webp` and I tested `-scale %s %s` but that was also giving me squared thumbnails of 256x256. On the other hand, the script calculates and gives the right proportional thumbnail size for x or y. ubuntu 16.04 here

Comment: There is a missing step here. You have to delete all cached thumbnails for Nautilus to be able to generate them again:  

`rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*`  
`rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/large/*`  
`rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*`  
`killall nautilus`

Comment: @pj.martorell interesting, I really dont remember having to do that, but apparently I probably did xD, btw, it could also be `nautilus -q`

Comment: I've tested the script on Ubuntu 14.04 to 21.04 and it's been working fine for both Nautilus and Nemo, though. Could you go into more details about this *"failing to generate the thumbnails but works to visualize'm"*?

Answer (score 30):

Some methods for previewing **WebP** images on Nautilus (GNOME Files) and Nautilus-based file managers (Nemo, Caja).

### For Ubuntu 21.04 and later

1. Install `imagemagick`

   ```
   sudo apt install imagemagick
   ```
2. Get the *MIME type* of WebP images

   - Right-click a WebP file, select *Properties*.
   - On the *Basic* tab, take note of what is in the parentheses for the *Type* field. It is usually `image/webp`.
3. Create a *thumbnailer entry* for WebP images

   - First, create a folder named `thumbnailers` in `~/.local/share`.

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/.local/share/thumbnailers
     ```
   - Create a file named `webp.thumbnailer` in that folder.

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/thumbnailers/webp.thumbnailer
     ```
   - Copy the following lines into the file (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into `nano` window):

     ```conf
     [Thumbnailer Entry]
     Exec=/usr/bin/convert %i[0] -thumbnail %sx%s png:%o
     MimeType=image/webp;
     ```
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`.

   *Note:* If the MIME type you got in step 2 is not in the third line listed above (the `MimeType` key), add it to the end of the line and optionally end the line with a semicolon (`;`).
4. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager

   - First, fully close the file manager with one of these commands:

     ```
     nautilus -q
     nemo -q
     caja -q
     ```
   - Next, delete cached failed thumbnails:

     ```
     rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
     ```
   - Optionally, delete all cached thumbnails:

     ```
     rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
     ```
   - Finally, reopen the file manager. WebP images should have their thumbnails now.

### For Ubuntu 14.04 to 20.10

1. Install `webp`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install webp
   ```

   This package provides the `dwebp` and `webpmux` tools, which will be used to convert WebP images into smaller PNG thumbnails.
2. Get the *MIME type* of WebP images

   - Right-click a WebP file, select *Properties*.
   - On the *Basic* tab, take note of what is in the parentheses for the *Type* field. It is usually `image/webp` (but it could also be `audio/x-riff` or even `application/x-wine-extension-webp`).
3. Create a *thumbnailer script* for WebP images

   - Create a file named `webp-thumbnailer-bin` in `/usr/local/bin`:

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/local/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin
     ```
   - Copy this script (based on the methods from [Script Echo Color](https://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secWebpPreview.sh) and [Aistis](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322204/1062200)) into the file (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into `nano` window):

     ```bsh
     #!/bin/bash

     sInFile="$1"
     nSize="$2"
     sOutFile="$3"

     # Check whether the input image is an animated WebP
     sInfo="$(webpmux -info "$sInFile")"
     nAnimation="$(echo "$sInfo" | grep --count animation)"

     # Get the dimensions of the input image;
     # For a still image, they are the width and height
     # of the canvas;
     # For an animated image, they are the width and height
     # of the first frame of the image, which might be
     # different from those of the canvas.
     if [[ $nAnimation -eq 0 ]]; then
         sSize="$(echo "$sInfo" | grep Canvas | cut --delimiter=' ' --output-delimiter=$'\t' --fields=3,5)"
     else
         sSize="$(echo "$sInfo" | grep '^ *1:' | sed -r 's|^ *1: +([0-9]+) +([0-9]+) .*|\1\t\2|')"
     fi
     nWidth="$(echo "$sSize" | cut --fields=1)"
     nHeight="$(echo "$sSize" | cut --fields=2)"

     # Get the version number of `dwebp`
     sVersion="$(dwebp -version)"

     # Calculate new dimensions for the output thumbnail;
     # `dwebp` 0.5.0 and later support using 0 as a scaling
     # dimension;
     # With older versions, the smaller dimension has to be
     # manually calculated (using `bc`).
     if [[ $sVersion < 0.5.0 ]]; then
         if((nWidth>nHeight)); then
             nNewWidth="$nSize"
             nNewHeight="$(echo "scale=10;f=$nHeight*($nNewWidth/$nWidth);scale=0;f/1" | bc)"
         else
             nNewHeight="$nSize"
             nNewWidth="$(echo "scale=10;f=$nWidth*($nNewHeight/$nHeight);scale=0;f/1" | bc)"
         fi
     else
         if((nWidth>nHeight)); then
             nNewWidth="$nSize"
             nNewHeight=0
         else
             nNewHeight="$nSize"
             nNewWidth=0
         fi
     fi

     # Generate output thumbnail;
     # If the input image is an animated WebP, the first
     # frame is extracted with `webpmux` and used as input
     # for `dwebp`.
     # Versions of `dwebp` older than 0.4.1 do not support
     # reading WebP data from standard input, so the frame
     # has to be written to disk first.
     if [[ $nAnimation -eq 0 ]]; then
             /usr/bin/dwebp "$sInFile" -scale "$nNewWidth" "$nNewHeight" -o "$sOutFile"
     else
         if [[ $sVersion < 0.4.1 ]]; then
             /usr/bin/webpmux -get frame 1 "$sInFile" -o "$sOutFile".webp
             /usr/bin/dwebp "$sOutFile".webp -scale "$nNewWidth" "$nNewHeight" -o "$sOutFile"
             rm "$sOutFile".webp
         else
             /usr/bin/webpmux -get frame 1 "$sInFile" -o - | /usr/bin/dwebp -scale "$nNewWidth" "$nNewHeight" -o "$sOutFile" -- -
         fi
     fi
     ```
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano` and return to the terminal.
   - Make the file executable with:

     ```
     sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin
     ```

   *Note:* If you use *Nemo* or *Caja*, you can place this script somewhere in your home directory and run commands like the above without `sudo`, for example:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
   nano ~/.local/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin
   chmod +x ~/.local/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin
   ```
4. Create a *thumbnailer entry* for WebP images

   - First, create a folder named `thumbnailers` in `~/.local/share`.

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/.local/share/thumbnailers
     ```
   - Create a file named `webp.thumbnailer` in that folder.

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/thumbnailers/webp.thumbnailer
     ```
   - Copy the following lines into the file (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into `nano` window):

     ```conf
     [Thumbnailer Entry]
     Exec=/usr/local/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin %i %s %o
     MimeType=image/webp;audio/x-riff;
     ```
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit `nano`.

   *Note:* If the MIME type you got in step 2 is not in the `MimeType` key above, add it to the end of the line and optionally end the line with a semicolon (`;`).
5. Clear old cached thumbnails and restart the file manager

   - First, fully close the file manager with one of these commands:

     ```
     nautilus -q
     nemo -q
     caja -q
     ```
   - Next, delete cached failed thumbnails:

     ```
     rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail
     ```
   - Optionally, delete all cached thumbnails (if you previously used unoptimized thumbnailer entries or scripts that created large thumbnails):

     ```
     rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails/*
     ```
   - Finally, reopen the file manager. WebP images should have their thumbnails now.

#### Notes

- Thumbnails for both *still* and *animated* WebP images will be created with the above methods.
- If you want the thumbnailer entry to be available to all users, place it in `/usr/share/thumbnailers` instead of `~/.local/share/thumbnailers`:

  ```
  sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/webp.thumbnailer
  ```
- A GUI text editor like `gedit` can also be used to create and edit the thumbnailer entry, but if you plan to place the entry in `/usr/share/thumbnailers`, using `nano` is [strongly recommended](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).
- Some details for `imagemagick`'s `convert` *(skip this if you don't want to know all the nitty-gritty)*:

  > `[0]` is specified so that, if the input image is an animated WebP, only the first frame is decompressed to a PNG thumbnail. Note that only `imagemagick` [6.9.10-68](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick6/blob/6.9.10-68/ChangeLog) and later (on Ubuntu 21.04 and later) support animated WebP encoding and decoding.

  > `-thumbnail %sx%s` is used instead of just `-thumbnail %s` or `-thumbnail x%s` to ensure that both the width and height of the output thumbnail are at most 256 or 128 pixels, which is in line with the [behavior of official thumbnailers](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/blob/master/libgnome-desktop/gnome-desktop-thumbnail.c). `-thumbnail %s` only limits the width and `-thumbnail x%s` only limits the height *(see [Image Geometry](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry) from ImageMagick)*.

  > The format of the output image file is explicitly specified with `png:` because Nemo, Caja, and certain versions of Nautilus [do not give output thumbnails a valid image extension](https://askubuntu.com/a/1368911/1062200). Without `png:`, `convert` would just [creates files in the same format as the input](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#output) (WebP in this case) for those file managers, leading to failed thumbnails.

---

### Other methods

*Notes:*

- Only thumbnails for *still* (non-animated) WebP images will be created when using one of the following methods.
- The steps are similar to the methods above, so only the differences are presented.

##### Use `gm` (for Ubuntu 16.04 and later)

- Install `graphicsmagick` which provides the `gm` tool:

  ```
  sudo apt install graphicsmagick
  ```
- The contents of `webp.thumbnailer`:

  ```conf
  [Thumbnailer Entry]
  Exec=/usr/bin/gm convert %i[0] -thumbnail %sx%s png:%o
  MimeType=image/webp;
  ```

##### Use `ffmpeg` (for Ubuntu 16.04 and later)

- Install `ffmpeg`

  ```
  sudo apt install ffmpeg
  ```
- The contents of `webp.thumbnailer`:

  ```conf
  [Thumbnailer Entry]
  Exec=/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i %i -filter scale=%s:%s:force_original_aspect_ratio=1 -f apng %o
  MimeType=image/webp;
  ```

  *Rationale: (skip this if you don't want to know the specifics)*

  > `-y` is specified to force `ffmpeg` to overwrite output thumbnails in the temporary directory. Without this option, failed thumbnails may not be regenerated.

  > The output format is explicitly specified with `-f apng` because Nemo, Caja, and certain versions of Nautilus [do not give output thumbnails a valid image extension](https://askubuntu.com/a/1368911/1062200). `apng` is actually for creating animated PNG files, but if the input is a still image, only a normal PNG is created.

  > `scale=%s:%s:force_original_aspect_ratio=1` is used so that the largest dimension of the output thumbnail is at most 128 or 256 pixels (which matches [the behavior of official thumbnailers](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/blob/master/libgnome-desktop/gnome-desktop-thumbnail.c)). See [FFmpeg's documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1) for the `scale` filter for more specifics.

##### Use `totem-video-thumbnailer` (for Ubuntu 14.04 and later)

- Install `totem` and `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`

  ```
  sudo apt-get install totem gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
  ```

  The `totem` package provides `totem-video-thumbnailer`, while the `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` package comes with the codecs needed by `totem-video-thumbnailer` to handle WebP images.

  *Note:* `totem` is the default video player on GNOME desktops, so it's pre-installed on Ubuntu.
- The contents of `webp.thumbnailer`:

  - For Ubuntu 16.04 and later (or `totem` 3.11.90 and later): see [Jan Broms's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1298785/1062200)
  - For older Ubuntu releases (or older `totem`):

    ```conf
    [Thumbnailer Entry]
    Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s --raw %u %o
    MimeType=image/webp;audio/x-riff;
    ```

  *Rationale: (skip this if you don't want to know the whys and wherefores)*

  > `totem-video-thumbnailer` from `totem` older than [3.11.90](https://github.com/GNOME/totem/blob/V_3_11_90/NEWS) add borders (film strip overlay) to thumbnails by default. The `--raw` option is used to disable that feature.

##### Use `dwebp` (for Ubuntu 14.04 and later)

- Install `webp` which provides `dwebp`

  ```
  sudo apt install webp
  ```
- The contents of `webp.thumbnailer`:

  - For Ubuntu 18.04 and later (or `dwebp` 0.5.0 and later):

    ```conf
    [Thumbnailer Entry]
    Exec=/usr/bin/dwebp %i -resize %s 0 -o %o
    MimeType=image/webp;
    ```
  - For older Ubuntu releases (or older `dwebp`):

    ```conf
    [Thumbnailer Entry]
    Exec=/usr/bin/dwebp %i -o %o
    MimeType=image/webp;audio/x-riff;
    ```

  *Note:* If you use *Nautilus* on Ubuntu 18.04 or later or *Caja* on Ubuntu 20.04 or later, which do *not* automatically scales down thumbnails larger than the default thumbnail size (128x128 or 256x256 pixels), then you should employ one of the other methods (with which output thumbnails are properly resized).

---

### Tested on

- Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, 20.10, 21.04
- Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon
- Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Comment: Excellent. This one worked for me. Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Thank you for sharing this :)
I tried adding animated WebP thumbnail support in my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1322204/449398) iterating on your answer. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: This also works in LMDE 4.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for this. Worth mentioning that you can list multiple mimetypes (that's what the optional semicolon does - it's a separator), so for example, your `convert` one can easily handle webp and avif formats together.

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions didn't work on my Ubuntu 20.04 and (after some stracing) I found Nautilus runs the thumbnailers through `bwrap` these days.

However, `/usr/bin/convert` on my comp is symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/convert` which in turn is symlinked to `/usr/bin/convert-im6.q16`. The problem is, since `/etc` as a whole does not happen to be bound by `bwrap` as it's used by Nautilus, the final path will not be found.

This works for me but you may need to adjust the exact path of `convert`:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/convert-im6.q16 -thumbnail %s %i %o
MimeType=image/x-webp;image/webp;image/x-dds;
```

Answer (score 2):

I followed [@CalicoCat's instructions for generating thumbnails for static WebP images](https://askubuntu.com/a/1223606/449398) and made changes to the code in order to generate thumbnails for animated WebP images. Tested on Linux Mint 20.1. In @CalicoCat's 3rd step, change the code to the one bellow.

**1. Edit the file (or create if missing)** `sudo nano /usr/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin` **and replace the code with the one bellow**

```
#!/bin/bash

strInFile="$1"
nMaxDimension="$2"
strOutFile="$3"

strInfo="`DISPLAY=NONE vwebp -info "$strInFile"`"
strSize="`echo "$strInfo" | grep Canvas | sed -r 's"Canvas: (.*) x (.*)"\1\t\2"'`"
nImgC="`echo "$strInfo" | grep VP8X | sed -r 's"VP8X: Found (.*) images in file \(loop count = (.*)\)"\1"'`"

nWidth="`echo "$strSize" | cut -f1`"
nHeight="`echo "$strSize" | cut -f2`"

if((nWidth>nHeight));then
    nNewWidth=$nMaxDimension
    nNewHeight=`bc <<< "scale=10;f=$nHeight*($nNewWidth/$nWidth);scale=0;f/1"`
else
    nNewHeight=$nMaxDimension
    nNewWidth=`bc <<< "scale=10;f=$nWidth*($nNewHeight/$nHeight);scale=0;f/1"`
fi

if [ "$nImgC" -eq 1 ]; then
    /usr/bin/dwebp "$strInFile" -scale $nNewWidth $nNewHeight -o "$strOutFile"
else
    /usr/bin/webpmux -get frame 1 "$strInFile" -o - | /usr/bin/dwebp -scale $nNewWidth $nNewHeight -o "$strOutFile" -- -
fi
```

If you weren't following @CalicoCat's instructions before then you need to do the other steps bellow.

**2. Next, make the file executable**

`sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin`

**3. Then create a webp.thumbnailer file in** `/usr/share/thumbnailers`

`sudo nano /usr/share/thumbnailers/webp.thumbnailer`

**4. Copy the following contents into the file**

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/webp-thumbnailer-bin %i 256 %o
MimeType=image/webp;image/x-webp;audio/x-riff;application/x-wine-extension-webp;
```

**5. Lastly, clear the thumbnail cache and regenerate thumbnails**

For Nautilus:

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/large/*
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*
nautilus -q
```

or for Nemo

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/large/*
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*
nemo -q
```

**Explanation of the changes I made from @CalicoCat's answer:**

I added a variable `nImgC` that gets the count of frames from the WebP file. If there is only a  single frame, then the WebP image is static. Else, the WebP image is animated. So we use `webpmux` to extract the first frame and then `dwebp` to save it as a usable thumbnail.

For the animated WebP image's thumbnail I'm using the very first frame because using any other frame can produce artefacts in the thumbnail (`-get frame 1` is the first frame, and `-get frame 0` is reserved for getting the last frame which often has pixels missing because of how some animations are compressed).

**Thanks to @ColioCat for the help**

Thanks to @ColioCat for cutting off 2 unnecessary cut calls and simplifying the code with a little pipping.

```
/usr/bin/webpmux -get frame 1 "$strInFile" -o - | /usr/bin/dwebp -scale $nNewWidth $nNewHeight -o "$strOutFile" -- -
```

The above code replaced the code bellow, where we first had to write our `webpmux` grabbed frame to disk, use it in `dwebp` to convert it to something usable by `nautilus` or `nemo`, and then remove it. As suggested, I'm leaving the original code snippet here.

```
    /usr/bin/webpmux -get frame 1 "$strInFile" -o "$strOutFile".temp
    /usr/bin/dwebp "$strOutFile".temp -scale $nNewWidth $nNewHeight -o "$strOutFile"
    rm "$strOutFile".temp
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works. Nice addition! Also, since we don't really need the `loop count` value, we could just use ``nImgC="`echo "$strInfo" | grep VP8X | sed -r 's"VP8X: Found (.*) images in file \(loop count = (.*)\)"\1"'`"``, which would save us 2 `cut` commands. But who knows, the `loop count` value might come in handy in the future.

Comment: @CalicoCat Nice. I'm still a greenhorn when it comes to Linux and bash. I just threw together something that seems to work and decided to share it as I had no luck finding an easy solution online. I don't think that `loop count` would ever be relevant to generating a thumbnail, but I still left it there for some reason. I'll update my answer to include your optimization if that's alright with you.
Also, maybe you know of a way to directly pipe the output from `webpmux` to `dwebp`? IIRC, the only way to do it is to save the frame first on disk, and only then to convert it. I might be wrong tho

Comment: I'm also pretty new to Linux myself xD. Anyway, I just took a look at the official documents from Google and found that you can indeed pipe the output from `webpmux` to `dwebp`, like this: ``webpmux -get frame 1 "$strInFile" -o - | dwebp -scale $nNewWidth $nNewHeight -o "$strOutFile" -- -``. I tested it but it seemed to only work on `nemo`. On `nautilus` or when used as a script, it did generate output files but failed to visualize them.

Comment: @CalicoCat It failed even when used as a script? As in a stand-alone bash script? For me it works fine on `nemo` and as a script. I can't say anything about `nautilus` but surely it should work as a script at the very least.

Comment: I just tested it again and... it really does work! Both as a stand-alone script and on `nautilus`! Guess I did too much testing yesterday so my box was a bit messed up... Anyway, with this I think it's pretty safe to update the script (2 more lines off!). Also, I'd suggest you still mention the original 3 lines (in the **Explanation** for example) to make it easier for others to troubleshoot if they have problems.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for your help, @CalicoCat

Comment: No prob! Glad to help.

Comment: I just made a number of improvements to the script so it is faster (and supports more releases) now. You might want to take a look.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a much simpler solution:

```
sudo apt install webp-pixbuf-loader
```

And that's it. Don't even need to restart Nautilus!

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=webp-pixbuf-loader indicates this is available from 22.04

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even have to refresh the folder view.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick has an option to convert webp and dds images. The full list of supported formats are here [ImageMagick formats](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported).

Remember for this to work you need first to install **ImageMagick**.

Now you can add a `webp.thumbnailer` file at `/usr/share/thumbnailers` with this lines:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/magick %i -thumbnail %s %o
MimeType=image/x-webp;image/webp;image/x-dds;
```

And finally clear actual cached thumbnails with this commands:

```
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory/*
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/large/*
rm ~/.cache/thumbnails/normal/*
nautilus -q
```

Comment: OP is about `nautilus`. Does that let nautilus to show webp? I don't see that happens. That said, +1 for mentioning `ImageMagick`. I didn't know it supports `webp` (even without the setting you posted. I'm on 20.04).

Comment: @IssacS This instruction can slowly differ for your environment. So you need to do a little research. Where are `thumbnailers`, `thumbnails cache` and `magick` command  located first. For me this instructions works well with `webp` images and they are shown in my file manager.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia Webp. As a derivative of the VP8 video format, it is a sister project to the WebM multimedia container format. So i tried totem-video-thumbnailer and it works.

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=image/webp;image/x-webp;
```