# Custom thumbnailers don’t work on Ubuntu 18.10 and 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus, 18.10, thumbnails

Recently I had a bunch of my own scripts for the thumbnails in Nautilus: [WebP previews](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617047/how-to-preview-dds-and-webp-images-on-nautilus), [sound waveforms](https://github.com/maximal/audio-waveform-php), office documents and so on.

Seems like either I’m doing something wrong (thumbnail generation behavior changed), or custom thumbnailes don’t work in latest GNOME at all, even my previous scripts, which worked smoothly on previous versions of Ubuntu.

I’ve done some research, tried to run a simple script (see below) and it didn’t work out.

My test thumbnailer in `/usr/share/thumbnailers/z.thumbnailer`:

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=/home/maximal/thumb.sh %s %i %u %o
MimeType=image/webp;image/x-webp
```

Where `/home/maximal/thumb.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0 >> /home/maximal/thumb.log
echo $1 >> /home/maximal/thumb.log
echo $2 >> /home/maximal/thumb.log
echo $3 >> /home/maximal/thumb.log
echo $4 >> /home/maximal/thumb.log
```

Then, when I remove thumbnail cache `rm -rf ~/.cache/thumbnails` and restart Nautilus `nautilus -q`, my log file doesn’t contain anything and `~/.cache/thumbnails/fail/gnome-thumbnail-factory` contains all the failed thumbs (looks like corrupted/empty PNGs):

[image: Failed thumbnail file]

So, apparently, Nautilus even didn’t try to execute my thumbnailer script.
When I try to run thumb command itself, it works perfectly. For example `convert` through `cwebp|dwebp` package:

```
convert -thumbnail 256x256 file.webp png:file.webp.png
```

When I wrap this command to a thumbnailer, it looks like it wasn’t even requested to run by Nautilus.

```
[Thumbnailer Entry]
Exec=convert -thumbnail %sx%s %i png:%o
MimeType=image/webp;image/x-webp;
```

Exactly the same situation occurs with other my thumbnailers: audio waveforms, office documents, photoshop files and so on.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Added 18.04 because the hardening causing this has been backported, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/1795668

Comment: Trying to study https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-desktop/blob/master/libgnome-desktop/gnome-desktop-thumbnail-script.c

Comment: I have opened a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/1808702

Comment: sasha-maximal, @jacek-kluza, marking the aforementioned bug with "affect me also" will confirm it and attract attention by the developers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've gone thru the same trouble with some of my external thumbnailers.

After some researches, I realised that bubblewarp call fails under Ubuntu and Debian based distros because of **--symlink** option on **/bin** and **/sbin**. In fact under these distros, /bin and /usr/bin are not merged. So, both should be declared with **--ro-bind** instead of --symlink.

To make **bwrap** call from Nautilus work under Ubuntu, you need to replace --symlink calls with --ro-bind calls for /bin and /sbin

To solve speed issue with thumbnailers using imagemagick tools, you also need to add a --ro-bind for /etc/alternatives and /var/cache/fontconfig

So, simplest solution is to place a wrapper script under **/usr/local/bin/bwrap** which will do the job and then call original /usr/bin/bwrap. As /usr/local/bin is before /usr/bin in the PATH, it is transparent for Nautilus.

Wrapper script is available on my [Github repo](https://github.com/NicolasBernaerts/ubuntu-scripts/blob/master/nautilus/bwrap)

I've written a small article to explain all into details and to provide wrapper script installation instruction. It has been tested under 18.04 and 18.10

http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/360-ubuntu-nautilus-external-thumbnailer-failure

Hope it helps

Comment: Interesting. The symlink things should be fixed, see the source code I linked above, but now that I think about it,  I am not sure it have percolated down to ubuntu. Will check your suggestion.  By the way, for sure you should add a binf for `/etc/alternatives` too... See my bug report... Thanks!

Comment: This is the patch I was mentioning https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/commit/259e7e4edb0d9b84fb7cf0847149ff8d42ab9a56

Comment: Ok: tested and it worked. So the problem is that the patch above has not been added to Ubuntu, yet. I will report this in my bugreport; please chime in if you can. And if you have time, please complete this answer so that it's a bit more informative. It solved my problem though, so I'll grant the bounty.

Comment: If you change the last line of your bwrap script to `/usr/bin/bwrap --ro-bind /etc/alternatives /etc/alternatives --ro-bind /var/cache/fontconfig /var/cache/fontconfig "${ARR_PARAM[@]}"` you solve this problem, the `/etc/alternatives` one, and the huge font generation slowdown...

Comment: Links for the above comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/issues/90 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/issues/92

Comment: I've added both --ro-bind needed by imagemagick in the parameters array initialisation in the bwrap wrapper script.
It should solve the problem, but I can't test it. Just let me know if it's ok.

Comment: I've added some more details in the answer.

Comment: Nicolas, tested, it works perfectly.

Comment: I installed your script and all thumbnailers (even “internal” ones) now fail (`~./cache/thumbnails` contains only `fail` directory). What could be wrong with this? https://i.imgur.com/lhpfx8k.png

Comment: Hi Sasha,
Few days ago, I've added a fix for 32 bits distros.
May be it is the source of trouble.
I've reverted the script on Github.
Could you download it again and see if it woks ?

Comment: Hi there! I installed both versions from your GitHub and they didn’t work. My system is Ubuntu 18.10 ×64 :-( Don’t know where the problem could be. I switched off all the external thumbnailers for now, but internal ones don’t work as well.

Comment: Hi, I tested today latest GitHub version on up to date 18.04 and it works fine. Make sure to delete $HOME/.cache/thumbnails directory. One interesting thing is that latest Nautilus doesn't use --symlink anymore. Patch with --ro-bind is operational. But --ro-bind for /etc/alternative and /var/cache/fontconfig is still not there. So /usr/local/bin/bwrap wrapper is still needed. Cheers

Comment: Solved! Since I needed PHP in my thumbnailers I should have added `[ -d "/etc" ] && ARR_PARAM=( "${ARR_PARAM[@]}" "--ro-bind" "/etc" "/etc" )` after `ARR_PARAM=( )` in your wrapper and move my thumbnailer out of my home directory (to `/usr/local`, for instance).

Comment: I can confirm that this works.  Excellent, thank you.

Comment: Please update the link to your article. I believe it's now: http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/360-ubuntu-nautilus-external-thumbnailer-failure. Also, it appears that latest Nautilus (3.36.3 on Ubuntu 20.04) has added `--ro-bind-try` for `/var/cache/fontconfig` and `/etc/alternatives` so custom thumbnailers work fine now.

Comment: Your script is probably still needed for systems that haven't applied these patches, however: [non-usr-merge patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/commit/259e7e4edb0d9b84fb7cf0847149ff8d42ab9a56), [font cache patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/commit/e83305b981ac160ba8bdd11cd44dd57aa57bb399), [/etc/alternatives patch](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/commit/df477a3d6c1b86f1913e6dbf3fcb587114d11606)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using 18.04, but after 2018.11.28 update I had same issue. It is caused by sandboxing thumbnailers with bubblewrap (it cost me 2 days of research!!!).

So I downgraded `gnome-desktop3-data`, `gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0`, `libgnome-desktop-3-17` (not sure if all 3 needed) and then removed bubblewrap.

It's a dirty hack and it weakens the security, but I don't care...

Maybe it will be not so easy on 18.10.

I hope somebody can write better solution...

Comment: WOW! You did a great research. I’ve spent a number of days, but didn’t figured the problem out.

Comment: This is caused by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-desktop3/+bug/1795668 . I have asked for a correct fix there, let's see... it's probably a matter of understanding how to write safe thumbnailers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 18.04 and I could not get the solution with the bwrap script to work.  I have a thumbnailer somewhere in my home path, which works under 16.04.  I can solve it in 18.04 by putting this program in /usr/bin.