# Ubuntu 18.10 GIF Thumbnails?

Tags: 18.10, thumbnails, gif

Anyone manage to get thumbnails for GIF files working in 18.10? None of the previous methods for adding a custom thumbnailer seemed to work for me like it did in past Ubuntu versions.

Comment: You might want to specify which methods are not working for you. Are you using the default GNOME DE?

Comment: Seems like custom thumbnailers don’t work in 18.10 at all. I have almost [the same issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088539/custom-thumbnailers-don-t-work-on-ubuntu-18-10).