# Getting thumbnails of cbz comics with images formatted in webp

Tags: thumbnails, zip, nemo, webp

So, I have a bunch of digital comics that are in cbz format (just a renamed .zip, for those who are less familiar) in which all the images inside the comics are in .webp format.

I am running Budgie 21.04, in case it matters, and I have gotten thumbnails for .webp images NOT in comics and thumbnails for comics that do NOT contain webp images. For comics thumbs I am using comicthumb which comes with MComiX, while for webp thumbnails, I have followed the information here: [How to preview DDS and WEBP images on nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617047/how-to-preview-dds-and-webp-images-on-nautilus/1223606#1223606?newreg=790757703ba34d7aaa2345959b4f5351).

My question, then is how to get thumbnails for those two things together. Any suggestions would be handy.

Comment: What does this have to do with the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Because I'm running Ubuntu? With the Budgie desktop environment? As I stated in the description?

Comment: Nothing in the question has anything to do with the OS or any apps included with the OS.

Comment: Well neither did the linked conversation, but people still helped. Also, considering that the issue IS a Linux issue, and IS based on the way the OS handles thumbnailing, it seemed relevant. But obviously the Ubuntu community is no longer as friendly and helpful as it used to be. So, thanks for gatekeeping and reminding the world why Linux will never make it mainstream, no matter what they do... some uptight asshole deciding that others don't deserve help.